# Formulation of a partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, boundary-value-problem

I am badly struck at this particular formulation of a boundary-value problem. Consider that a function's second partial derivative equals a constant throughout a well-defined circular domain. There are two boundary conditions- one on the bound of the domain, where the flux of the function vanishes and another at each small circular domain inside the big circular domain, where the function has a fixed value. i.e there are small circular regions inside the big circle containing them.
$$ k_1\nabla^2\cdot f=R\ \ \ , [x,y\in\Omega=\{x^2+y^2\lt1\}]\\q\cdot\hat{n}=0, q=\nabla\cdot f\ \ \ , [x,y\in\partial\Omega]\\f=k_2\ \ \  ,[x,y\in\partial\Gamma_i]\ \ \ ,\Gamma_i=\{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2\lt r^2\},\\ \texttt{where each small circle lies entirely inside the unit circle}\ \\0\lt x_i,y_i,r\lt1$$.
How can we formulate the above as a poisson equation with well known boundary conditions like Dirichlet, Neumann etc.? Also, how can we numerically find the maximum possible value of $R$ for a given threshold $f$? Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

The problem arose in a study modeling oxygen diffusion in blood capillaries scattered in a striated muscle fibre bundle. Note that the small circles represent the capillaries and the unit circle represents the muscle fibre bundle.

Comment: Once you have the boundary condition on $\Gamma $ you can no longer enforce the PDE inside $\Gamma $. With that aside your problem becomes just a mixed BC Poisson equation on a complicated geometry. This particular type is related to a class of problems studied in transition path theory.

Comment: @Ian sorry,what do you mean?

Comment: Just what I said: you can't make a condition on $\nabla^2 f $ inside the region on whose boundary you are requiring $f=k_2$. Or at least, if you do, there is no guarantee of good regularity between the interior and exterior problems.

Comment: @Ian You mean to say that we have to solve the PDE for each $\Gamma$ seperately, is it? But, what about the boundary condition on $\Omega$?

Comment: The point is that there is an exterior problem with BCS on $\partial \Omega $ and all the $\partial \Gamma_i $, which is not defined inside the $\Gamma_i $. That problem is totally separate from all of the problems on the $\Gamma_i $. You also could have a discontinuous gradient across $\partial \Gamma_i $.

Comment: @Ian modified the domain $\Gamma$, please view now

Comment: I caught that typo already, my point was relative to the corrected version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59801/discussion-between-vidyarthi-and-ian).